# Two divs with background

Tags: html, css

I have navigation on my site with background-color, opacity 0.2. I want to make a separate background for list links menu and make left part of navigation with logo to be floated with own background till next div. I've tried a bunch of methods but all them seem to be imperfect. Left side with logo background just occupies space under text not whole div as I need to.

Here's example:

```js
$('.navigation ul li a').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('navigation-hover');
}).on('mouseout', function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('navigation-hover');
})
```

```css
.navigation {
  font-size: 3em;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.navigation-logo {
  float: left;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.navigation ul {
  display: inline;
}

.navigation ul li {
  float: right;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  line-height: 60px;
  height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.navigation-hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="navigation-logo">
    <a class="navigation-logo">logo</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try giving `height: 100% ` to `.navigation-logo`, and see if it helps. As you have given `float:left` which has detached the container from normal DOM flow.

Comment: yeah, its understandable with height but what about empty space on width. I can use instead of float: left like display: inline-block but its all about same

Comment: Or, you can use `flexbox`
Refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Comment: Yeah, it seems for me as single option, thanks for heads up

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Styles go here */

.navigation {
  font-size: 3em;
  height: 70px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 8px;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  display: flex;
  left:0;
  position:fixed;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.navigation-logo {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.navigation ul {
  display: inline;
}

.navigation ul li {
  float: right;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  line-height: 60px;
  height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.navigation-hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}
    here is plunkr for the above changes

    http://plnkr.co/edit/0PY5IPExNYVwQPsOVyXS?p=preview
```